# How to Access Shared Computer Through Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, path

I have Mavericks on my Mac and wish to set up Unison between it and an old PC (vaiolaptop) running Windows XP on my network. How so I specify the path to the remote machine?

It appears like so in finder and I can navigate through it in Finder just fine.

[image]

Comment: If it has SMB You can check Terminal command: `mount_smbfs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first created a  mapped network drive of the folder I wanted access to following [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224140022/http://www.usciences.edu/it/helpdesk/forstudents/MacDriveMapping.shtml). (YES, `smb://<windows machine network name>` worked to reference my windows machine without having to do any sort of configuration or installation on that machine.) Then merely specified path to the mounted drive under `/Volumes/`.